# How can I save RGB 565 using libiff?

Tags: c++, image, tiff, libtiff

I'm trying to save an RGB 565 image, but i can't seem to get the bit samples right.

`TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, ...)` seems to get receive only one short. But I need 3 separate sizes to R G and B.
The TIFF specs says the BitsPerSample field should get an array of short with the bit all the bit samples.

So, how can I save RGB 565 using libiff ?

Comment: As far as I know, TIFF doesn't support RGB565. I've never come across one in the wild.

Comment: @BitBank The TIFF spec says you can set BitPerSample value for each sampled (RGB). So it should be able to. It can be done manually of course, the question is how i can do it with the Libtiff API. I probably need to override the TifFieldInfo for TIFFTAG_BITPERSAMPLE somehow

Comment: If you succeed, please post a sample file so that I can add support to my imaging library.

Comment: It's probably just as easy (and a lot more compatible) to just convert to RGB 888. But sounds like a fun exercise. I'd like a sample as well. ;-)

Comment: @haraldK I don't have the processing power to loop over the image on the machine i'm using. (embedded system)

Comment: Long time later, but in case other people end up here like me: although TIFF format supports RGB565, libtiff does not.